# Does WebSphere Liberty support Microsoft Active Directory Application Mode for LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, websphere-liberty

Does WebSphere Liberty support Microsoft Active Directory Application Mode for LDAP authentication in ldap-security features.

I see Microsoft Active Directory listed but not application mode.

Answer (score 0):

Any directory that supports LDAP v3 should work with Liberty. Based on the schema for the directory being used one might have to update the LDAP filters to fit the directory requirements.

So if your ADAM schema matches the default filters that we use for AD, it should work without changing the filters. If they are different, you can tweak them to fit the ADAM schema.